# Trouble allocating memory to pointer in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a pointer variable of type char declared in this way:

```
char *name;
```

So to turn it into a string of 80 characters i did the next thing:

```
name=malloc(sizeof(char)*80);
```

this worked fine at school but when i came home i got this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

the compilers are exactly the same as are the compile and build code.

what is the problem?

Comment: Are you compiling in C++ mode?

Comment: In C, `void*` is compatible with any other pointer type. You are likely compiling in C++ mode where an explicit cast is required for `malloc()` (then again, why are using `malloc` in C++?).

Comment: wait that's the problem... i made a cpp instead of c, haha

Comment: I can't edit it any more...

Comment: @iharob why so serious ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` returns a pointer of type `void*`. `void*` is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type in C , but not in C++. The error can only appear if you are compiling in C++ instead of C. You **should** cast the result of `malloc` if you are compiling in C++ and **should not**, if you are compiling in C.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to different compiler versions/compiling mode!

The solution is:

```
char * name;

/* 81 bytes because in C the strings must be terminated by a binary code 0x00.
- ASCII0 strings  */

name = (char *)malloc(81*sizeof(char));

----------------------------------------------------------
```

The malloc function is declared as:

```
void *malloc (size_t __size)
```

then is better you manifest your intent using casts!

Another example:

```
int *numbers;

numbers=(int *)malloc(200*sizeof(int));
```

that allocates memory space for 200 integer values.

Comment: Good catch on 81 vs 80.  Disagree on "better you manifest your intent using casts!"  Using `name = malloc(81 * sizeof *name);` is easier to code and maintain.  NMDV

Comment: Yes, right! name=malloc(81*sizeof(*name)); is more easy to mantain. :)